# Break script tag to run C# loop

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery

I'm a bit stuck with a tracking script I'm attempting to implement in a C# app. I need to loop through the basket items in a cart, but I don't know how to break the script tag to let the C# loop process so that each item can be iterated over. Example code below (I've added comments in to attempt to make this clearer):

```
@if (Model != null)
{
<script>
            $(function () { // START JAVASCRIPT
                console.log('Ticket type: @Model.BasketItems[i].Name');
                console.log('Price: @Model.BasketItems[i].Price');
                console.log('Quantity: @Model.BasketItems[i].Quantity');
                dataLayer.push({
                    'event': 'calendarCheckout',
                    'ecommerce': {
                        'detail': {
                            'products': [ // END JAVASCRIPT
                            // START C# LOOP
                            @for (var i = 0; i < Model.BasketItems.Count; i++)
                            {
                                if (Model.BasketItems[i].Quantity > 0)
                                {
                                    { // BREAK C# LOOP
                                    // JAVASCRIPT
                                        'name': '@Model.BasketItems[i].Name',
                                        'id': '',
                                        'price': '@Model.BasketItems[i].Price',
                                        'brand': 'Some Brand',
                                        'quantity': '@Model.BasketItems[i].Quantity'
                                    },
                                    // END JAVASCRIPT. FINISH C# LOOP BELOW

                                }
                            }
                            // FINISH C# LOOP
                            // START JAVASCRIPT
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                });
            });// FINISH JAVASCRIPT
</script>
}
```

Any guidance on how to achieve this would be appreciated. Currently, due to similar syntax, the C# loop items are being rendered incorrectly as JS.

Thanks,
Mark.

Comment: When you need comments like that, it's time to seriously rethink things. It's a very strong indicator.

Comment: Sorry. I should have been more direct. This is bad. Stop doing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of trying to generate json in a loop, I would serialise the whole json;

```cs
var products = @Html.Raw(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model.BasketItems.Where(i => i.Quantity > 0)));
```

You could also use a `<text>` tag in your loop, but I'm not certain if the razor html parser works perfectly with tags nested in scripts.

```cs
if (Model.BasketItems[i].Quantity > 0)
{
    <text>
        ....
    </text>
}
```